# Validates Numericality Ruby on Rails Can't Enter Float Price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My price column in my table is in type float.

I am trying to use the validates_numericality_of from the rails guide to doing some number validations.

This is the number text box from the form

```
  <li>
    <%=f.label :price, 'Asking Price:'%>
    <%= f.number_field :price %><span class='columnLabel formtext'>USD</span>
  </li>
```

I have this in the model

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0
```

I want to make sure the price is a number, is positive, and can be a float and that it exist.

When I head to the form and try to enter 4.44, I keep on getting a pop up that says the nearest integer is 4 or 5 and I should enter valid values.

I have tried something like this too

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :only_integer => false
```

I do have this too

```
attr_accessible  :city_id, :title, :price
```

so price can be mass assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 number inputs only accepts integers by default.

Try `f.number_field :price, step: 'any'`